# Sortable image gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to create a sortable image gallery using Jquery UI Sortable. Until here, works fine.

Inside each tag, I need to store the order of each image in the gallery. But this order must be updated when an image is moved.

Example: I have five images:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="1" value="1">image 1</li>
  <li id="2" value="2">image 2</li>
  <li id="3" value="3">image 3</li>
  <li id="4" value="4">image 4</li>
  <li id="5" value="5">image 5</li>
</ul>
```

If I move the image 4 after image 5, the order values ​​should not be changed. That is, the image 5 has the value 4 and the image 4 has the value 5.

This is possible?

Comment: Your last two sentences are in conflict. You say the order values should not be changed, but explain that images 4 and 5 should have new order values when they are moved in the sortable. Would you edit your question with a fuller explanation?

Comment: Also, if you could show us what you have thus far (say on a JSFiddle) that would be very helpful for context.

Comment: Why do you need to store the value in the element? You could just get the index on the fly.

Comment: Here is my current state: http://jsfiddle.net/D3DaH/
What I would like is that when the image 4 was moved to after image 5, its value (value = "") were upgraded to their current position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update the value in the event `stop` when the sort just ends. Something like this :

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).children("li").each(function(index) {
            $(this).attr("value", index);
        });
    }
});
```

Like this, you can save the new values on the server if you want to keep this display after a reload.

EDIT: correcting the way to set index thanks to [marcelo2605](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633525/marcelo2605)

Comment: Is something like this. But the value is not updating when I drag the image: http://jsfiddle.net/D3DaH/1/

Comment: Fixed: $(this).attr("value", index);